# How to prevent Selection Changed event of dataGridView when binding data into dataGridView?

Tags: c#, datagridview

This is selection changed event of dataGridView it fires three times and causes error in the code which is used to select a particular row cell value :

```
private void dataGridView1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {       
                int i;
                i = dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex;
                lblIdValue.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString();    
        }
```

Comment: do you delete data from your grid?

Comment: Do not subscribe to event, until data are bound. Unsubscribe for a time when you finish with something what shouldn't trigger event, re-subscribe after. Use *flag* to be set, when event rising will be ignored. Perhaps there are even more solutions.